# Error installing X Window System on CentOS 9

Tags: linux, centos

I'm trying to install "X Window System" on CentOS 9, when using `yum update` and `yum groupinstall "X Window System"`, I'm getting this type of error:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:20:05 ago on Sun 27 Feb 2022... 
Module or Group 'X Window System' is not avalible.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: CentOS 9 Stream : Did you check "available" with `dnf grouplist` ?

Comment: I tried that but there is no way how to scroll so I have no idea what groups are there.

Comment: The command is `dnf grouplist | less` to be able to see all the choices. .... AFAIK it is like "Server with GUI" and "Workstation", i.e. ".. a user-friendly desktop .." ← Ref. the CentOS 9 Stream "Netinstall / CentOS-Stream-9-..-boot.iso".

Answer (score 0):

As @knud-larsen mentioned, you may see different groups using

```
$ dnf grouplist
...
Available Environment Groups:
   Server with GUI
...
```

So the first option is

```
$ sudo dnf groupinstall "Server with GUI"
```

The second option is found while executing the command above. There are more groups actually and they are shown before prompt to continue. One of them is `GNOME`:

```
$ sudo dnf groupinstall GNOME
```

It looks like that GNOME is only available out of box. Maybe you can install other desktops as well. The group `base-x` may be helpful here to install basic X Windows stuff.

There is no automatic startup of GUI after installing the group:

1. Do it manually

   ```
   $ startx
   ```
2. Change start-up target:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
   ```